# Firestore Security Rules Error: Property id is undefined on object when using get() function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**Error:** Error: simulator.rules line [13], column [27]. Property id is undefined on object.

**Security Rules:**

```
    rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
        function isBusinessOwner() {
          let businessDocId = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.managedBusinesses[0].id;
          let businessTeamUserId = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/businesses/$(businessDocId)).data.team[0].id;
          return request.auth.uid == businessTeamUserId;
        }

    match /businesses/{businessDocId} {
      allow read, write: if true;

      // Sub-collection:
      match /businessCustomerQueue/{queuedCustomerDocId} {
        allow read, write: if isBusinessOwner();
      }
   }
    
      }
    }
```

**Code explanation:**

1. `users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.managedBusinesses[0].id`: User document contains a `managedBusinesses` array field which it's first index `[0]` is a Firestore reference type. Then trying to access the `id` property on that reference type.
2. `businesses/$(businessDocId)).data.team[0].id`: Business document contains a `team` array field which it's first index `[0]` is a Firestore reference type. Then trying to access the `id` property on that reference type.

The first `get()` function call failed in the `isBusinessOwner()` function call.

The Rules Playground `get()` function call relevant portion of the data that was returned is:

```
"managedBusinesses": [
"/databases/%28default%29/documents/businesses/TMCVfCRemRlaUdQjumrn"
]
```

The first element of the `managedBusinesses` array appears to be a string, however, the error message is stating it's an object and the actual field data type in Firestore is a reference type to a document.

Why am I getting `undefined` when trying to access the `id` property on this reference type in Firebase security rules.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Solution:

```
function isBusinessOwner() {
  let businessDocPath =  get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.managedBusinesses[0];
  let businessOwnerDocPath = get(/$(businessDocPath)).data.team[0];
  return /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid) == businessOwnerDocPath;
}
```

When dealing with Reference types in Firestore Security Rules, the reference type is simply a string type and has no properties to access. Therefore, you need to compare a path such as `/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)` to the reference type. This operation is ultimately a string comparison.